# Handle same inputs group with jquery (show/hide)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show/hide some elements in one div when I check the checkbox. I want to show div under, but for each group separately. All div's "addNar.." I'm create dynamically by append with jquery.

**html code**

```
<div id="naramky">
    <div id="addNar1">    
       <input type="checkbox" id="heart" name="heart[]" class="heart" value="1">
         <div id="srdce" class="srdce" style="display:none">
           <input type="text" id="srdce_farba" name="srdce_farba[]" />
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addNar2">    
       <input type="checkbox" id="heart" name="heart[]" class="heart" value="1">
         <div id="srdce" class="srdce" style="display:none">
           <input type="text" id="srdce_farba" name="srdce_farba[]" />
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addNar3">    
       <input type="checkbox" id="heart" name="heart[]" class="heart" value="1">
         <div id="srdce" class="srdce" style="display:none">
           <input type="text" id="srdce_farba" name="srdce_farba[]" />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code in js file**

```
$('#naramky').on('click', '#heart', function() { 
   $('#srdce').toggle();

});
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Convert id heart to  class heart

Comment: @AlivetoDie you delete your answer?

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think I find the problem...problem is with dl,dt,dd tags in my append code. If I replace them with div everything is working...

Comment: if it working then use it.Apart from that you have css to change look and feel

Comment: I'm just editing...yes i will change css for divs..or you think css of whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="heart[]"]', function() {
  $(this).parent().next('.srdce').toggle();
});
```

@AlivetoDie its yours but I delete one of parent() you send me with two like "parent().parent()"